# Assigning variables from an array where property doesn't always exist

Tags: php

I'm using an API that returns search results in json.  I decode this to a PHP array and can pick out the elements I need from there by looping over the array and assigning the elements as variables so that I can store the values in a database.

My issue is that there can be one or several dozen properties returned, it just depends on the search parameters.  If I do this,

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://search-query-url&output=json"));

foreach($array as $cur) {
  $key1 = $cur->item_title;
  $key2 = $cur->item_url;
  $key3 = $cur->item_location;
  echo $key1 . " " . $key2 . " " . $key3 "<br>";
  }
```

...all is well unless item_location (key3) doesn't exist in the json output.  In such cases, I get the error "Undefined property: stdClass::$item_location."

The property name (item_title, item_url, etc) is important because that is how I know what table column the value/string should be stored in.

I'm stumped trying to figure out this problem, and I'm not quite sure where to go.  Trying to use in_array or in_object but I must be doing something wrong.  I need to create variables based on the corresponding property name, when it exists.

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My usual technique for a situation like this is to

1. use `json_decode($var, true)` to decode the data as an associative array instead of an object.
2. Use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to set default values for any keys that I depend upon.
3. If some fields are optional, and you need to know whether the user provided the input or not, use `false` or `null` as the default value.

This eliminates the syntacticly unpleasant repetitive key-checking.

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://search-query-url&output=json"), true);
$defaults = array(
    'item_title' => 'Default Title',
    'item_url' => 'default url',
    'item_location' => false
);
$array = array_merge($defaults, $array);

// check to see if we have a location or not using !==
if ($array['item_location'] !== false) {

}
```

I actually prefer the object syntax, but PHP has tons of useful array manipulation functions.  Also, many PHP programmers are more comfortable with arrays than objects.

Comment: So far, so good - thank you!  Would you recommend that I use "false" or "null" for any/all of the fields that are not required?

Comment: Use a value that either (a) wouldn't be allowed from the user, or (b) would be a reasonable default.  Just be sure to use the `===` comparison operation when checking for your 'not provided' values.  Because PHP does so much type-conversion for you, it is easy to run afoul of the fact that `'' == 0` and `0 == false` and `false == null`.  The `===` operator doesn't allow type conversion, so `false === null` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, use `json_decode("JSON_STRING", true);` to make it return an array and not an object.

Once you do that, `array_key_exists()` would work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the variable is set and if not assign a value of blank to that key.

```
foreach($array as $cur) {
  $key1 = (isset($cur->item_title))?($cur->item_title):('');
  $key2 = (isset($cur->item_url))?($cur->item_url):('');
  $key3 = (isset($cur->item_location))?($cur->item_location):('');
  echo $key1 . " " . $key2 . " " . $key3 "<br>";
}
```